# HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE(tls_record.cc:594)) using IOClient and private certificate

Tags: flutter, authentication, http, ssl, soap

I need to be able to use a personal certificate as authentication to a soap server and I'm receiving the error `HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE(tls_record.cc:594))` if I use

```
       var request = http.Request(
              'post',
              Uri.parse(
                  'https://homolog.sefaz.go.gov.br/nfe/services/NFeStatusServico4'),
            );
```

and I get `Connection reset by peer` if I use

```
       var request = http.Request(
              'post',
              Uri.parse(
                  'http://homolog.sefaz.go.gov.br/nfe/services/NFeStatusServico4'),
            );
```

I have the certificate in the assets folder and load using the following code

On the `Main()` I have the following:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request();

  ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('assets/cert/imperiocert.pfx');
  SecurityContext.defaultContext.setTrustedCertificatesBytes(
      data.buffer.asUint8List(),
      password: 'mypassword');
HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();
```

and on the same `main.dart` I have the following code

```
class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context) {
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) {
        //Store cert in xcert variable to try extract expiring date, serial number, etc.
        xcert = cert;
        return true;
      };
  }
}
```

And finally, I call the snip below in an `ElevatedButton

```
             var request = http.Request(
              'post',
              Uri.parse(
                  'https://homolog.sefaz.go.gov.br/nfe/services/NFeStatusServico4'),
            );
            request.headers.addAll(headers);

            request.body = arquivoxml.toXmlString();
            final context = SecurityContext(withTrustedRoots: true)
              ..useCertificateChainBytes(certificate, password: 'mypassword')
              ..usePrivateKeyBytes(certificate, password: 'mypassword');

            final ioClient = ioh.IOClient(HttpClient(context: context));
            print('<------------------------------------->');
            print(request.toString());
            print('<------------------------------------->');
            try {
              final response = await ioClient.post(request.url,
                  headers: request.headers, body: request.body);
              print(response.body);
            } catch (e) {
              setState(() {
                retonochamada = e.toString();
              });
              print(e);
            }
```

It always return `HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE(tls_record.cc:594))`

```
Changed from "https://homolog.sefaz.go.gov.br/nfe/services/NFeStatusServico4" to "http://homolog.sefaz.go.gov.br/nfe/services/NFeStatusServico4" and the error is "Connection reset by peer".
```

The calls I need to make are for a soap server, need to authenticate and send a XML as request and read a XML as response.

Checked the emulator date and time, they are the same as the server timezone

My certificate is valid until **02/2024**

I have no idea on what to do, and any help woud be very much appreciated.

J.